# Make cx_Freeze to add app to startups

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

How can I make cx_Freeze to make the app created to start on windows startup? I can't find the answer to any questions like this.

As in start on startup, I mean when the computer boots, the program automatically starts. I also would like this to be done automatically in first use of the program.

Comment: Would like it to be automatic.

Comment: What is not automatic about it?

Comment: Would like a code that can add it to startup. The not automatic part comes from having to manually add the program the startups list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `win32` library to create a shortcut to your exe and place it in the startup folder.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os

dir = r'C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'
name = 'shortcut.lnk'
path = os.path.join(dir, name)
target = '<your exe>'
working_dir = '<working directory>'
icon = '<file to take the icon from, can be your exe>'

shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = working_dir
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

Comment: The path should have `r'`, as a best practice - that, or escape the backslash `\\ `, or use forward slashes `/`

Comment: Edited my post :)